# Why adding an item to collection returns 204 status code? Why is it using POST method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Assuming we have a group and users entity (with many-to-many relation):

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
}
```

We also created `CrudRepository` for each entity.

[Specs of spring-data-rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) say that in order to add item to that collection you need to POST user's uri into `/users` resource, like here (using `rest-assured`):

```
given().contentType("text/uri-list").
        body('/users/123').
        then().
        post('/groups/123/users');
```

This works well and user is actually added to a group, but API brings some questions:

1. Why is it using POST instead of PUT method? In ReST world POST usually means creating a new resource, as an adding item to collection is rather updating it.
2. Why is it returning 204 status code? Shouldn't that be 201?
3. When I try to add user to the same group twice API returns 204 in both cases - shouldn't second call be responded with 409?
4. Is there a way to configure that behavior, so adding item to collection would cause 201 or 409 if that resource is already in associated collection?
5. What if I want to add user to multiple groups at once? Should I do one HTTP request for each group? Should I create custom controller for such batch operation? Should I add `groups` property to `User` class?
6. Am I overthinking here? :)

My project is using `spring-boot`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is the operation supposed to be idempotent?

Comment: you mean adding user to a group? Yes. You cannot add him twice.